# to modify a query in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query which gives a result like this

```
field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
23      gfhf    ghjj       5        49
23      ghf     jkll       6        45
67      bnvn    nmb        7        45
89      gfh     hjj        8        78
89      gfhg    hk         9        23
```

Here the first 2 and last 2 records are kind of same.
I want only one based on field 4 and field 5.
i.e whichever has the minimum value in field 4 and maximum 
in field 5.

I want the following result

```
field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
23      gfhf    ghjj       5        49
67      bnvn    nmb        7        45
89      gfh     hjj        8        78
```

Thanks

Comment: I think your stated desired code is contradictory. For ID 23, you're taking the MAX() of Field2, but for ID 89, you're getting the MIN(). This is not consistent. Likewise for Field3, for ID 23, you've taken the MIN() but for ID 89, the MAX(). If the results you present are really what you want, I just don't see any SQL method of getting that, unless there's some data left out that determines whether you want MIN() or MAX() for a given collapsed row.

Comment: actually i am not considered about field 2 and field 3 i am only concerned about field 4 and 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First establish the minimum value for field 4 and the maximum value for field 5 that you want to associate with field 1.

```
SELECT field1, Min(field4) AS MinField4, Max(field5) AS MaxField5
FROM Table1
GROUP BY field1;
```

Save this query as, say Query1 then join it back onto Table1 to get the values for field2 and field 3.

```
SELECT Query1.field1, Table1.field2, Table1.field3, Query1.MinField4,
       Query1.MaxField5
FROM   Query1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON (Query1.field1 = Table1.field1) AND
       (Query1.MinField4 = Table1.field4) AND
       (Query1.MaxField5 = Table1.field5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your ordering correct you will need to create a new query which takes the input as the your existing query.

To make it easiest adjust your current query so the result are ordered in the way you wish, with field4 Ascending and then field5 Descending

Create a new query selecting all the values from your existing query

In the designer for this new query, right click and add totals
Select Group By for field1 and then First for all the other ones

This should do what you want

Comment: wouldnt this give all the records by just sorting them based on field 4 and field 5 .

Comment: thats what the Totals stop. They pick the first row in the sorted query for each value of field1